# if statement returns false, while it is true

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, python-requests

I have
(>)as input

```
color = ['grey', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'white']
nickcolor = input()
>red
nickcolor in color
>True
```

Then I write

```
if nickcolor in color == True:
    print('You are now logged in ' + nickname + ' !\n Write something in chat!')
else:
    print('Error occured. Please restart.')
>Error occured. Please restart.
```

Why does in if statement it is a false?

Comment: You don't need the `== True` at all; comparing a Boolean value to `True` just yields the original value (that is, `x == True` is equivalent to `x`).

Comment: Just fix it with paranthesis ```if (nickcolor in color) == True:``` it will work.

Comment: Why add even more to an already overly verbose expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to Python's operator chaining logic:

```
nickcolor in color == True
```

is actually being parsed as

```
(nickcolor in color) and (color == True)
```

`color` is not equal to `True`, so the whole condition is `False`.

In this case, it's accidental, but this logic is usually used for arithmetic comparisons, in which it's quite handy:

```
0 < x < 10
```

instead of

```
0 < x and x < 10
```

Note that none of this is actually needed here, since `nickcolor in color` is already a condition, you can write your `if` like this:

```
if nickcolor in color:
```

Comment: Thank you for an explanation; have you an idea how can I do it to have it as True?